# Calculating the variance of a population

Tags: probability, statistics

> The following sample shows 10 different values for the voltage of a
>   cable:
>
> 57, 64,  68,  66,  54,  60,  48,  46,  75,  62
>
> Find the mean and the variance of the population.

My professor did this
[image]

[image]

Why didn't he use this formula for the variance?

[image]

I suppose that the fact that it asks for the variance of the population and not of the sample probably has something to do with it but I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we have

$$s^2=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2}{n} =\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2-n\cdot \overline x^2}{n} $$

This is the variance of a sample and a $\textrm{biased}$ estimator for the variance of the population. Now we want an $\textrm{unbiased}$ estimator $s_u^2$ for the variance of the population. This is

$$s_u^2=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2}{n-1} =\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2-n\cdot \overline x^2}{n-1}$$

$s_u^2$ is unbiased since $\mathbb E\left(s_u^2 \right)=\mu$

Comment: Why do we want an unbiased estimator? Why not just use the formula I posted like in most exercises I've been doing so far?

Comment: You want to estimate the variance of the population. The it is good if the estimator is not biased. For instance the variance of the population is $4$. But you estimate and calculate with the biased variance of $4.5$. This wouldn´t make sense if you can do it better.

Comment: Right. So when do I use my professor's formula and when do I use the other one?

Comment: In your previous exercises the variance of the population was given, I think. So there was no need to estimate the variance of the population. Every time if the variance of the population is not given and you have a sample you have to estimate the variance of the population. If the variance of the population is given, then there is no need to estimate the variance.

Comment: But isn't the other formula about finding the variance of the population too?

Comment: If you have the data of the whole population (this is not a sample) then you can use  the formula for $s^2$. But here you do not estimate the variance. And sometimes it is asked for the variance of the sample, then you use the formula for $s^2$ as well.

Comment: You use the *unbiased estimator* ($s^2$) when you only have a *sample* of the population's statistics; when you *are* estimating the population's variance. You use the *actual* variance ($\sigma^2$) when you *do* have the *entire* population's statistics; when you are *not* estimating anything.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have the population, just a sample with size n = 10. Now, this is important, 'n' is the size of the sample, and 'N' is the size of the population which you don't have. So, since you don't have the population itself you can't use the $\sigma^2$ formula because it requires some informations of the population as 'N' to work. Most of the time we don't have the information of the population itself, so we need to work with a sample to estimate parameters of that population, and the best estimators for the mean of the population is $\bar{X}$ and for the variance is $S^2$, because they attend some criteria that good estimators have, some examples of those criterias are unbiasnedness, consistency, efficience, minimium variance.